# Error(writeError code 2) while updating

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Getting writeError (code 2) while updating document in mongoDB.

Following are the code :

```js
db.transactions.insert(
    { 
         _id: 1, 
         source: "A",
         destination: "B", 
         value: 100,
         state: "initial", 
         lastModified: new Date()
   }
)


var t = db.transactions.findOne( { state: "initial" } )

db.transactions.update(
    { "_id": t._id, "state": "initial"},
    { 
        "$set": { "state": "pending" },
        "$currentDate": { "lastModified" : true }
    }
)
```

The last statement in above code is failing with error :

```js
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 2,
            "errmsg" : "cannot compare to undefined"
    }
})
```

Need help with understanding why this error is thrown and the correct update syntax.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "two phase commits" therefore your reference is removed. I supsect your actual code is in another language ( i.e NodeJs ) or at least something else than presented here. The error is clear. Your `.findOne()` did not find anything. I'm hinting towards "Node" here because it's an "async" API and your actual calls are likely not "waiting" for the result of that operation before performing the `.update()`. Hence "undefined". For clarify, the "cut and paste" of this listing here works for everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your code **Jatin**, please ensure that you are properly pasting in the mongo shell, I blindly copied pasted your code in my mongo shell and it worked. Pasting the screenshot for your reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/or71q4ma8rbt4iz/mongo_txn_err_code_issue.png?dl=0

Also, you can refer mongo doc for the same example and in detail discussions about it.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Let us know if you need any further help around this.

Happy Mongoing :-)

-$

Comment: Thanks. You were right.. It was a copy paste issue.. Could you please share any reference document link (if any) where these error codes are defined? Or are these self-explanatory?

Comment: you may find some here, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/exit-codes/ but its exit codes..apart from that 11000 which is for duplicate key..http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/